# Read a XML file with XStream

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I have this xml:

```
<testsuite name = "testsuite1" time = "19.0" tests = "2" skipped = "0" errors = "1"  failures = "1">
<testcase name = "test1" time = "10.0">
    <failure type = "testcase" message = "error"></failure>
</testcase>
<testcase name = "test2" time = "9.0">
    <failure type = "testcase" message = "error"></failure>
</testcase>
```

I define 3 clases:

TestSuiteBean.class

```
public class TestSuiteBean {

private List<TestCaseBean> testcases;

@XStreamAsAttribute
private String name;

@XStreamAsAttribute
private long time;

@XStreamAsAttribute
private int failures;

@XStreamAsAttribute
private int tests;

@XStreamAsAttribute
private int skipped;

@XStreamAsAttribute
private int errors;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public long getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(long time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public int getFailures() {
    return failures;
}

public void setFailures(int failures) {
    this.failures = failures;
}

public int getTests() {
    return tests;
}

public void setTests(int tests) {
    this.tests = tests;
}

public int getSkipped() {
    return skipped;
}

public void setSkipped(int skipped) {
    this.skipped = skipped;
}

public int getErrors() {
    return errors;
}

public void setErrors(int errors) {
    this.errors = errors;
}

public List<TestCaseBean> getTestcases() {
    if (testcases == null) {
        testcases = new ArrayList<TestCaseBean>();
    }
    return testcases;
}

public void setTestcases(List<TestCaseBean> testcases) {
    this.testcases = testcases;
}
```

}

TestCaseBean.class

```
public class TestCaseBean {

private FailureBean failure;

@XStreamAsAttribute
private String name;

@XStreamAsAttribute
private long time;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public long getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(long time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public FailureBean getFailure() {
    return failure;
}

public void setFailure(FailureBean failure) {
    this.failure = failure;
}
```

}

FailureBean.class

```
public class FailureBean {

private String type;
private String message;

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
```

}

and the main.class

```
final XStream xStream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
    xStream.setMode(XStream.ID_REFERENCES);
    xStream.alias("testsuite", TestSuiteBean.class);
    xStream.alias("testcase", TestCaseBean.class);
    xStream.alias("failure", FailureBean.class);

    FileInputStream file;
    try {
        file = new FileInputStream("config1.xml");
        TestSuiteBean xml = (TestSuiteBean) xStream.fromXML(file);
```

and i get next error:

Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Element testcase of type el2.test.zephyr.read.TestCaseBean is not defined as field in type el2.test.zephyr.read.TestSuiteBean
---- Debugging information ----
class               : el2.test.zephyr.read.TestSuiteBean
required-type       : el2.test.zephyr.read.TestSuiteBean
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
line number         : 4

### version             : null

Answer (score 0):

`testcase` actually appears multiple times, so I guess you need to replace:

`xStream.alias("testsuite", TestSuiteBean.class)`

with

`xStream.addImplicitCollection(TestSuiteBean.class, "testcases", 
    "testcase", TestCaseBean.class)`